# Applying Bottom Box Shadow leaves some unshadowed space on left and right bottom sides

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
<div id="navigation">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the following CSS

```
body
{
width: 100%;
background-color: #E4E4E4;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 19px;
font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}

div#wrapper
{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url("nav_bg.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 219px;
}

div#container
{
width: 920px;
background-color: #F9EADE;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgb(31, 73, 125);
margin: 0 auto;
}

div#navigation
{
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 200px;
background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

The nav_bg.png is this

[image]

And I get white unshadowed space in the bottom left and right

[image]

If I change the code to this

```
div#navigation
{
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 200px;
background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

I get additional shadow on left and right sides as this.

[image]

And If I remove background-color and border-shadow from the div#navigation as follows.

```
div#navigation
{
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

I get this

[image]

Sorry I messesd up the question real bad before.

Comment: @Usman: Edited and included code.

Comment: You already hav a shadow on the PNG, why would you add more using CSS? USe one or the other or you're bound to run into problems.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: For some reason when I remove background-color and box-shadow from the div#navigation, the blue strip does not show in the middle and only left and right sides triangles show up.

Comment: THis is because you've applied the BG to the page wrapper, not the navigation.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: But if I remove the BG from div#wrapper and move it to div#navigation and remove bg-color & border-shadow from the div#navigation, it does not show at all.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: Like this but I can't get the images to work. - http://jsfiddle.net/vH8Bc/2/

Comment: @Deefour: How would I use your masking out technique in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just make the div little wider so it would reach to the sides.
If you could show the code, I could show you how.

EDIT:
Just add minus margin to left and right to navigation and add width so it would reach the sides what you need

```
margin: 0 -20px 200px;
width: 947px;
```

EDIT2:
If this does not work then there is something that you are not showing or you're doing it wrong.

```
body
{
width: 100%;
background-color: #E4E4E4;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 19px;
font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}

div#wrapper
{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url("oBecq.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 219px;
}

div#container
{
width: 920px;
background-color: #F9EADE;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgb(31, 73, 125);
margin: 0 auto;
height: 500px;
}

div#navigation
{
height: 50px;
margin: 0 -10px 200px;
background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
box-shadow: 0px 10px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
top: 219px;
position: relative;
width: 950px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have the shadow spread property set to -4px (the fourth number)

Set it to 0 and it will appear as you wish.

```
box-shadow: 0 10px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/evd4K/

Comment: sorry i have to make a new question. You soultion does not work maybe because of my html. I wil include the html or just edit the baove question.

Comment: I really messed up the question. Tried to delete it and make new but could not. I will just edit it.